# ¿Como manejar la excepcion java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1?

Tags: java, array, formularios, excepciones

¿Como podría mostrar una validación o mensaje de error para que la clase solo me acepte archivos de texto plano con un formato `array` de 9 posiciones?
Quisiera mostrar un mensaje que diga: **formato no valido al momento de generarse el error**
este es el formato de txt: ,00123,Articulo,Azul,grande,99.00,90.00,2,En Stock
Ya que cuando subo cualquier archivo de texto me marca el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at
>   Mod_Naranja.Subirtxt.SubirActionPerformed(Subirtxt.java:264)

Dejo una parte de mi código. Gracias.

> *Mi linea 264 inicia en la parte de String sql="INSERT INTO articulo...

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       try {
            String[] arr = line.split(",");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO articulo "
                     + "(id_articulo,codigo,nombre_articulo,desc_articulo,tam_articulo,precio_men,precio_may,id_categoria,status) "
                     +  "VALUES ( null ,'" + arr[1] + "','" + arr[2] + "'" +
           ",'" + arr[3] + "','" + arr[4] + "','" + arr[5] + "','" + arr[6] + "','" + arr[7] + "','" + arr[8] + "') ";
            s.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error "+e);   
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Articulos cargados");
 }
```

Comment: Podrías usar un condicional para verificar el tamaño del `array` antes de continuar con el bucle. Cada vez que declaras `String[] arr = line.split(",");` puedes hacer un `if(arr.length != 9) {System.out.println("error de formato"); break;}` o pudieras usar otro bloque `try...catch` anidado para capturar la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Es cuestión de que decidas tu lógica.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo como esto puede ayudarte.

```
 int fila = 1;
while((line =br.readLine())!=null) {
    try {
        String[] arr = line.split(",");
        if (arr.length == 9) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO articulo "
                    + "(id_articulo,codigo,nombre_articulo,desc_articulo,tam_articulo,precio_men,precio_may,id_categoria,status) "
                    + "VALUES ( null ,'" + arr[1] + "','" + arr[2] + "'" +
                    ",'" + arr[3] + "','" + arr[4] + "','" + arr[5] + "','" + arr[6] + "','" + arr[7] + "','" + arr[8] + "') ";
            s.execute(sql);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la fila: " + fila + " Solo tiene "+arr.length+ " columnas.");
        }
        fila++;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Articulos cargados");
}
```

Sin embargo, un buena práctica sería que solo insertarás registros, si y solo si todos los registros del archivo fueran validos. Todos se registran o ninguno. Si un registro es incorrecto el archivo de datos cargado debería ser rechazado.

Comment: Me parece una excelente respuesta. No solo planteas una solución, sino que además das un consejo de buena práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el metodo length de los arrays. Esto te devuelve la longitud del array para que no te pases de su indice. Utiliza eso que te devuelve para controlarlo en un bucle y asi no salirte del indice, que ese es el error que te esta dando.

Comment: gracias por contribuir con tu respuesta. Pero añadir ejemplos con código resulta de mucha mas utilidad. [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente ese error, se da cuando quieres obtener un valor de un posición que no existe en el array, como indican mas arriba tienes que validar, las posiciones que devuelve el array saludos.

Comment: gracias por contribuir con tu respuesta. Pero añadir ejemplos con código resulta de mucha mas utilidad. [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)